# Image formation of object on itself by a system of a lens and a mirror

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

Suppose there is a lens and a mirror. An object is placed in front of this system (nearer to the lens). If the final image of object (refraction, reflection and again refraction) is formed on the object itself, then must the each ray falling on the mirror be perpendicular to the mirror so that it can retrace its path? Is there no other situation except this in which the image of the object will form on the object itself?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rays don't have to be perpendicular to the mirror for this to happen. Here is an example.

Let the lens be a converging lens of focal length $f$. If the object is a distance $2f$ away from the lens, and the lens is a distance $2f$ away from the mirror:

1. The image of the object through the lens is co-located with the mirror, inverted and real. Call this image 1.
2. The image of image 1 through the mirror coincides with image 1, and is inverted (relative to the object orientation). Call this image 2.
3. The image of image 2 through the lens is co-located with the object, upright (relative to the object) and real. Therefore it coincides with the object.

The rays forming image 1 and reflecting off the mirror are not all perpendicular to the mirror. What's happening here is each ray not retracing its own path, but that of *another ray* emitted from the same point in the object. So each ray transmitted through the optical system ends up at the point it was emitted from.

Comment: Yeah! but Let the 1st image not forms at mirror and it is at some distance from mirror then will it be possibe ,( we are allowed anything to do for that)

Comment: The final image will coincide with the object only if the first image is formed either at infinity (the case you mention in your question) or on the mirror (as in the example I gave).

Comment: But I have a situation when object isn't forming at infinity neither at mirror but final image is forming at object.

Comment: The rays becoming parallel to each other and the optical axis (and perpendicular to the mirror) after going through the lens the first time as in your case means the first image is formed at infinity, which is just another way of saying the rays don't intersect (i.e. are parallel).

Comment: In my uploaded case 1st image is forming at 1.2m behind the mirror so 2nd image will form at (1.2-0.8)=0.4m in front of mirror so final image will be image of 2nd image which will be formed by lens, but here no any image is forming at infinity neither at mirror ,

Comment: Why do you think the third image coincides with the object? If you are convinced that it does, then why ask the question? Also please explain your figure. Does $\mu$ refer to refractive indices? This by itself isn't sufficient to determine where images will form, the radii of curvature of the lens are also necessary.

Comment: I sincerely apologise for that. Radius of curvature given is 0.3m and it is equiconvex lens. Yes μ is refractive index ( 3/2 is of lens and 4/3 is of liquid) and ray of light is coming from air, btw I am not assuming image is forming at object, after calculations I got that,

Comment: The final image is a virtual image formed 0.9 m _behind_ the lens (i.e. on the side opposite the object). It does not coincide with the object.

Comment: Final is forming at 0.9m from lens on the same side of object and the image is real. As 2nd image is at 0.4m from lens

Comment: I'm sorry but that's incorrect. You are right about the location of the second image but not the third image. I'm also not sure what you are looking for at this point, for someone to confirm that the final image in this case forms at the object location? It doesn't.

Comment: Sorry I was doing mistake with signs. I was really amazed after getting that wrong result that how can it be possible but now I got it. Thanx for your concern, and again sorry for wasting your time on behalf of my mistake.